# Can't boot ubuntu, showing GNU grub menu instead

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I can't boot Ubuntu, instead it shows me the GNU Grub menu.
Until yesterday, it worked fine but now it's stuck at gnu grub menu.
The items in the gnu grub menu are:

1. Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-22-generic
2. Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-22-generic (recovery mode)
3. Memory test (memtest86+)
4. Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

Which one should I select? I selected the first one but it shows me the command line.
what should I do?

Note: I'm using only one OS(that's Ubuntu10.10)

Comment: Anyone?????????

Comment: What is Ubuntu version?

Comment: 10.10 - @Pilot6

Comment: This version is not supported for many years.

Comment: @Pilot6 - so what should i do?

Comment: I suggest installing something that is supported. If you have that old hardware, Lubuntu 14.04 will probably do.

Comment: @Pilot6 - What about my data in the computer? is there anyway to boot ubuntu?

Comment: The easiest way is to write a Lubuntu LiveUSB if your computer can boot from USB, or a LiveCD. Then boot from it and backup your data.

Comment: @Pilot6 - OK, Let me see if I can backup my data in a live cd...thanks

Comment: @SLY That data is on your HDD regardless of if you can boot Ubuntu 10.10 ever again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry, but Ubuntu 10.04 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said selecting the first option shows you the command line. I'm gonna assume you arrived at that without the login screen, so that must be a tty screen.

Type

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

and you should get the login screen.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later type:

```
sudo systemctl start lightdm
```

and you should get the login screen.

Comment: it shows me: `/bin/sh: sudo: not found`

Comment: should i rescue my system with a live CD?

Comment: Looks like you don't have sudo functionality. That's either because of an incomplete linux installation or that you're already root (su).
Try without sudo and tell me what happens.

Comment: `/bin/sh: service: not found`

Comment: It's an incomplete linux installation. You should use the LiveCD, format the linux partition and install again.

Maybe before doing that, you should verify if your Live CD doesn't have a corrupt version of Linux.

Comment: Rescuing the system won't work?

Comment: Rescuing means  administrating or repairing your system and data after a crash. By what you said, it appears that your system never started in the first place. You don't have any data on it, do you?

Comment: No really...it worked fine until yesterday, but all the sudden it's not starting(the computer was plugged off yesterday& from that moment on it's not booting)

Comment: I recommend a fresh install. Doesn't take long. Sorry could't answer your original question.